# Machine Learning feature-engine MeanEncoder gives error with Cancer dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm working with the wisconsin breast cancer dataset found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data). Feature engineering is important in machine learning so a teacher of mine recommended the MeanEncoder part of a library found [here](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.x/encoding/MeanEncoder.html). The dataframe looks like the following:

[image]

I did specifically change the diagnosis feature/column to category because one of the errors said that might of been the issue but apparently not as it's not solved.

I want to mean encode the target feature/column using MeanEncode found in the library linked above. Here's my function to attempt to do so:

```
def MeanEncoding(self):
   # Get the columns besides the target variable at the front, which is diagnosis, as recommended by teacher.
   cols = self.m_df.iloc[:, 1:].columns.to_list()

   # Save specifically the target variable too.
   target = self.m_df.iloc[:, 0]

   # Now get the object ready.
   encoder = MeanEncoder(variables=cols)

   print('---Fitting---')

   encoder.fit(self.m_df.drop('diagnosis', axis=1), target)
```

In this code:

1. m_df - just the dataframe hence the "df"
2. I drop the diagnosis column/feature in the first argument of encoder.fit, since it's provided in the 2nd argument of the same function. But it means nothing. Because I still get the error: "**TypeError: Some of the variables are not categorical. Please cast them as object or category before calling this transformer**"

Now with #2, I'm thinking, "No way, I have to transform the numeric features which are 'radius_mean', 'texture_mean', etc into category or object? That makes 0 sense". But I google this error of course and it brings me to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843146/how-to-handle-numerical-variables-in-categorical-imputer-transformer). This individual is having similar concerns like me except with a different function. The suggestion for him was "*Just change the dtype of grade column to object before using imputer*", so I change the types as well to object with the following code:

```
for i in range(1, len(self.m_df.columns)):
   columnName = self.m_df.columns[i]
   self.m_df[columnName] = self.m_df[columnName].astype('object')
```

Doesn't make sense to me because it's converting the types of genuine numeric columns/features. I get this error which is KIND of expected:

```
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Now I'm thinking it just wants a few numeric types, so I slightly alter the code:

```
  for i in range(1, len(self.m_df.columns) - 2):
      columnName = self.m_df.columns[i]
      self.m_df[columnName] = self.m_df[columnName].astype('object')
```

Which literally just leaves the last 2 columns as float64 types and therefore all others are type object (besides the diagnosis column which is category but I doubt that matters). Now some numeric types ARE present. Yet I still get the error again

```
TypeError: Some of the variables are not categorical. Please cast 
them as object or category before calling this transformer
```

I am clearly missing something but not sure what. No matter how I alter the types to satisfy the function, it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The MeanEncoder from Feature-engine, as well as all other Feature-engine encoders, work only on variables cast as object or category by default.

So the variables captured in the list `cols` in this line of code: `cols = self.m_df.iloc[:, 1:].columns.to_list()` should only contain categorical variables (object or category).

When you set up the encoder here: `encoder = MeanEncoder(variables=cols)`, in `variables`, you indicate the variables to encode. If you pass `cols`, it means you want to encode all the variables within the `cols` list. So you need to ensure that all of them are of type category or object.

If you get the error: `"TypeError: Some of the variables are not categorical. Please cast them as object or category before calling this transformer"`it means that some of the variables in `cols` are not of type object or category.

If you want to encode numerical variables, there are 2 options: 1) recast the variables you want to encode as object. 2) set the parameter `ignore_format=True` as per the [transformer's documentation](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/encoding/MeanEncoder.html). That should solve your problem.